# sorting problems

Tags: excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel, excel-2010

I have a situation like this in excel 2007:

```
.15X.04-1.25X.625-SD+str

.15X.04-1.25X1.25-SD

.15X.04-1.5X1.25-SD

.15X.04-1.75X1.75-SC

.15X.04-1X.625-SD+str

.15X.04-2.25X2.25-SC

.15X.04-2.5X2.5-SC

.15X.04-2.75X2.75-SC

.15X.04-2X1.75-SC

.15X.04-3X3-SC

.15X.06-1.25X.625-SD+str

.
.
.
.
```

I need to sort all of these line by part of content in each cell, like this:
`-1X; -1.25X; -1.5X; -1.75X` and so on .

how can i do it?

Comment: I tried cell color and font color, couldnt work well. only 2 options, top and buttom, i need some options in between

Comment: I upvoted this question just because so many people downvoted it.  Why are people downvoting it?  It seems like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to extract the value from your text. As you indicated in the comment, this is between `-` and second `X`, so you can use this formula to extract it and convert it to a number:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,SEARCH("X",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"X","_",1))+1-SEARCH("-",A1)-2))
```

Note that this will return you the value if you're on an English system (with `.` as the decimal separator. If you're on a system with another separator, you need to use this formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,SEARCH("X",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"X","_",1))+1-SEARCH("-",A1)-2),".",","))
```

(the last `","`must be replaced with your local decimal separator.)

Apply this formula to the whole column and then sort this column.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new column with this formula: `=MID(A1;8;500)`, assuming your original column was A, and copy this formula to all the *column*, then sort by this new column. The formula will copy just the part you want to sort by.

Comment: is there any fucntion like: only copy the words between "-" and "X" ?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in @Peter Albert answer.